# Unbound block list , How to know from query log that if domain blocked or not?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, unbound

I have configured an Unbound server with domain block list, blocking works perfectly fine.
But from the query log, i can only see that blocked domain is queried, that's it.
I tired with

```
server:
local-zone: "00009483.com" always_refuse
```

and increased log level as well, but i cannot able to find any indication that this domain refused / blocked .
Is there any configuration do i need to update ? or is it possible to add custom query message for blocked domains?

Answer (score 1):

Enable log-local-actions in unbound.conf

```
log-local-actions: yes
```

For troubleshooting a blocked domain, I set verbosity to 1 and log-local-actions to yes in unbound.conf to show only blocked domains.